# How to Add Rewrite Ruled Argument Into Permalink Properly

Tags: rewrite-rules

I am using WP rewrite rules for my custem arguments,
But when I am trying to generate permalink like this:

```
add_query_arg(array(
    'type' => 'foo',
    'paged' => 2,
),get_permalink($id)) ;
```

It returns still:

```
mysite.com/products/?type=foo&paged=2
```

But I need to turn it into this:

```
mysite.com/products/foo/2
```

Rewrite rules work perfectly, but "add_query_arg"..

How to solve?

Comment: `add_query_arg` is for adding [query string arguments](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), not for generating pretty permalinks. what context are you using this in exactly? have you already added your `type` query var and added a rewrite rule to handle incoming requests via `add_rewrite_rule`?

Comment: @Milo I added a few rules via "generate_rewrite_rules" action

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm affraid this "nasty" solution would be the most effective than trying to write some cool function that will translate your permalinks into pretty permalinks:

```
$permalink = rtrim( get_permalink( $id ), '/' ) . '/foo' . '/2';
```

The rtrim part (removing trailing slash) is just for to be sure there are not going to be two slashes on the end of the first part of your new pretty permalink.

Comment: The simple is the golden, you are right.. Sometimes it is effective doing it manually than building a framework in a framework :)